# How to optimize this code that read from xml file

Tags: asp-classic, msxml

We have ther following classic asp code that read from xml file, it shows a poor performance when there are more than 10 concurrent requests to that page , can someone figure out the performance problem in this code( we know one of the the problems which is using fileSystemObject but we do not have alternatives for it!):

```
set filesys=server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if filesys.FileExists(sourcefile) then  
 set source = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
 source.validateOnParse = false
 source.resolveExternals = false
 source.preserveWhiteSpace = false
 source.load(sourcefile)  

If source.ParseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
   str_head=source.selectSingleNode("/LIST/ITEM/NEWSITEM/HEADLINE//").text

   str_by=source.selectSingleNode("//LIST//ITEM//NEWSITEM//PROVIDER//").text

   News_date_orig = source.selectSingleNode("/LIST/ITEM/NEWSITEM/CREATED//").text
   str_date= formatdatetime(source.selectSingleNode("//LIST//ITEM//NEWSITEM//CREATED//").text,1)
   set bodyNode=source.selectSingleNode("/LIST/ITEM/NEWSITEM//BODY//")
   styleFile=Server.MapPath("/includes/xsl/template.xsl")
   Set style = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
   style.validateOnParse = false
   style.resolveExternals = false
   style.preserveWhiteSpace = false
   style.load(styleFile)
   news_full = bodyNode.transformNode(style)
   if len(news_full) < 10 then
   news_full = str_abstract 
end if 
DiscriptionKeyWord = stripHTMLtags(news_full)
DiscriptionKeyWord=StrCutOff(DiscriptionKeyWord, 200, "...")
headerTitle=str_head
Set style=nothing
Set source = nothing
end if
set filesys= nothing
```

The following is stripHTMLtags function:

```
Function stripHTMLtags(HTMLstring) 
  Set RegularExpressionObject = New RegExp 
  With RegularExpressionObject 
   .Pattern = "<[^>]+>" 
   .IgnoreCase = True 
   .Global = True 
  End With 
  stripHTMLtags = RegularExpressionObject.Replace(HTMLstring, "") 
  Set RegularExpressionObject = nothing 
End Function
```

**UPDATE:** I put a timer to show the execution time for the function that read xml file and found that it takes around 3 seconds on the production server while it takes less than 1 second on my PC! What does tht mean?! I'm lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option Explicit**

If your scripts don't begin with `Option Explict` then make that change now.  Then fix all the compile errors that show up.  Doesn't help performance but when I see evidence that this biggest of all scripting mistakes is being made it just needs mentioning.

**FileSystemObject**

I doubt the performance problem is a result of the `FileSystemObject`, all you are doing is creating an instance and testing for the existance of a file.  That is hardly likely to cause a problem.

Having said that I would ditch the `FileSystemObject` anyway.  Just let the script throw an error if there is a problem.  Use IIS Manager to map 500.100 status codes to an ASP page that presents a friendly "Something bad happened" page to the user.  (500.100 is the status of a request when the script throws an exception).  Also test the boolean result of the DOM `load` method, throw an error when parse error is not 0 also.  That way you hand over all the ugly exception handling to the 500.100 handling page and your code can remain clean just dealing with the nominal path of the code.

**Tidy up the paths**

Perhaps there is a reason why you are using "//" a lot in your paths (but inconsistently) but I'm going to assume there isn't so we can simplify some of the paths:

```
Dim newsItem: Set newsItem = source.selectSingleNode("/LIST/ITEM/NEWSITEM")

Dim str_head: str_head = newsItem .selectSingleNode("HEADLINE").text 

Dim str_by: str_by = newsItem .selectSingleNode("PROVIDER").text 

Dim News_date_orig: News_date_orig = newsItem .selectSingleNode("CREATED").text 
Dim str_date: str_date = formatdatetime(News_date_orig, 1)

Dim bodyNode: Set bodyNode = newsItem.selectSingleNode("BODY")
```

**Cache XSLTemplate**

An area where you could gain some real perfomance improvement is to cache the XSL Transform in the application object (which is possible due to `XSLTemplate` being a free threaded object). Like this:

```
Dim xslTemplate
If IsObject(Application("xsl_template")) Then
    Set xslTemplate = Application("xsl_template")
Else   
    Set style = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0")
    style.async = false    
    style.validateOnParse = false    
    style.resolveExternals = false    
    style.preserveWhiteSpace = false    
    style.load Server.MapPath("/includes/xsl/template.xsl")

    Set xslTemplate = CreateObject("MSXML2.XSLTemplate.3.0")
    xslTemplate.stylesheet = xsl
    Set Application("template") = xslTemplate
End If

Dim xslProc: Set xslProc = xslTemplate.createProcessor()
xslProc.input = bodyNode

xslProc.transform()   
news_full = xslProc.output
```

The effort to read, parse and compile the XSL transform is only done once in the whole lifetime of the application.

**The most likely culprit**

To be honest I suspect the most likely culprit is `stripHTMLtags`.  This sounds like a whole load of string handling and the performance of VBScript string handling is poor.  Its especially poor when code is not properly optomised to be aware of the string handling performance limitations (e.g. excessive and repeative string concatenations).  Its also likely to be where the most actual VBScript occurs which is often the cause of a performance problem.

Comment: I do not think stripHTMLtags is the reason,here its body:Function stripHTMLtags(HTMLstring)
 Set RegularExpressionObject = New RegExp
 With RegularExpressionObject
 .Pattern = "<[^>]+>"
 .IgnoreCase = True
 .Global = True
 End With
 stripHTMLtags = RegularExpressionObject.Replace(HTMLstring, "")
 Set RegularExpressionObject = nothing
End Function

Comment: @Cassini:  Comments are not a good place to put code.  Please edit your question and include the code for `stripHTMLTags` in it.

Comment: Edited...as you can see it's using reguler expression.

Comment: @cassini: In that case I would concentrate on optomising the use of xsl template to see if that helps first.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the XML into a string on application startup and store it in an `Application` object.

Then, instead of using `source.load`, use `source.loadXML` with this string - you will not be accessing the filesystem anymore. See the documentation for [`loadXML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Make sure you use a version of `MSXML` 3.0 or over to use this method.

```
Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
```

---

Update - seeing as you have thousands of these files and you believe it is infeasible to store them in memory in the `Application` object, you should be using a database to handle the concurrency issues you are seeing. Store the contents of the files keyed to something like their current filename/path - retrieve them from the database and load to a document using the same `loadXML` mechanism.

Comment: Not possible because we have thousands of xml files that read from. I already tried msxml version 6 for that code but got many problems

Comment: @Cassini - If you can't cache the files you may have to use a database to store them instead.

Comment: @Cassini - Do you have version 6 installed? You can use 3.0, 4.0 instead.

Comment: Yes it's installed also 4.0 give problem...My code is using 3 BTW.

Comment: @Cassini - Can you be more specific regarding your "I cannot make it work" statement? I don't know what that means.

Comment: Nevermind it works now...thank you, but how that will enhance the performance?

Comment: @Cassini - If one assumes that the access to the filesystem is the bottleneck, taking that away should help.

Comment: we need filesystem to check if the xml file exist if not then download the xml and the save it in xml file.